# ShareKit for iphone - SHKShareTypeText

Tags: iphone

I am using ShareKit for iphone to share some text in facebook. Can any one tell me which delegate is called after publishing the text successfully. I need this to inform the user that his action was successful.

Answer (score 1):

The shareDelegate property in SHKSharer isn't the easiest to get to and change, but there are notifications sent from the delegate methods of SHKSharer, one for each of the methods: SHKSendDidStartNotification, SHKSendDidFinish, SHKSendDidCancel, SHKSendDidFailWithError. Observing these notifications turns out to be a simple way of listening for the outcome of sharing.

Answer (score 0):

See shareDelegate property of [SHKSharer](https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/blob/master/Classes/ShareKit/Core/Base%20Sharer%20Classes/SHKSharer.h) .  All the concrete sharers (e.g. SHKFacebook) extend this base class.

Having said that, I'm not sure where you set a class to be the delegate using ShareKit's public API (so I'm not claiming this to be a complete answer).